# how to prove limit of $x_{n-1}$ converges rigorously

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Hi I am having problem with proving $x_{n-1}$  converges to $x$ when $x_n$ converges to $x$. Intuitively, it seems obvious. But when it comes to proving it by using rigorous mathematical definition of limit, I get
 lost... Need your help!!

Comment: Note:  Please check my edits to make sure I didn't accidentally change your meaning.

Comment: Not at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{y_n\}$ be a series defined by $y_0 = \text{anything}, y_k = x_{k-1}$.  By hypothesis, assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$; that is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a value $N$ such that for all $n > N, |x_n - x| < \varepsilon$.

Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, it is also true that there exists an $M$, namely $M = N+1$, such that for all $m > M, \ldots$?

Answer (score 1):

Given any fixed $\epsilon>0$, we can find an $N\in\mathbb{R}$, such that for all $n>N$, we have $$|x_n-x|<\epsilon$$
so that we can find $N+1\in\mathbb{R}$, such that for $n>N+1$, we know that $n-1>N$, so 
$$|x_{n-1}-x|<\epsilon$$
and thus, $x_{n-1}$ converges to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Express that $x_n$ converges to $x$, using the formal definition.

In the formal definition, replace $n$ by $n-1$.

Then see the relation.